# Appium Android PointerInput LongPress code is needed

Tags: android, appium

Faced error: Encountered internal error running command: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Exception while reading JSON

Have coded in java and showed the appium logs here.

My code:

```
{
 "id": "finger",
 "type": "pointer",
 "parameters": {
 "pointerType": "touch"
 },
 "actions": [
 {
 "duration": 0,
 "type": "pause"
 },
 {
 "duration": 0,
 "x": 862,
 "y": 747,
 "type": "pointerMove",
 "origin": "viewport"
 },
 {
 "button": 0,
 "type": "pointerUp"
 }
 ]
 }
 ]
 [
 {
 "id": "finger",
 "type": "pointer",
 "parameters": {
 "pointerType": "touch"
 },
 "actions": [
 {
 "duration": 0,
 "type": "pause"
 },
 {
 "duration": 0,
 "x": 862,
 "y": 747,
 "type": "pointerMove",
 "origin": "viewport"
 },
 {
 "button": 0,
 "type": "pointerUp"
 }
 ]
 }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for long-press operation for the recent appium version without touch action and javascript.

```
Point element_location = WebElement.getLocation(); //Getting element's location
      long_press(element_location);// passing the location coordinates to the long_press funcation
      PointerInput finger = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "finger"); 
     Sequence longpress = new Sequence(finger, 1);
    longpress.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(0),PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), location.x, location.y));
    longpress.addAction(finger.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
    longpress.addAction(finger.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(2000),PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), location.x, location.y));
    longpress.addAction(finger.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
    driver.perform(Collections.singletonList(longpress));
```